# I have 400 json files in a folder and I want to create 400 lists of that name in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I have 400 json files in a folder and I want to create 400 lists of that name. 
So, for example, I have these 4 json files: john.json ; rick.json; tom.json; sean.json
Now I want to create 4 lists in Python containing the data of each of these json files. I want to do this in a loop

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to do that but I am new to StackOverflow, so could not do.
so for example, I have JSON files,  john.json ; rick.json; tom.json; sean.json. I want to create 4 lists containing data of these four JSON files
I am doing in this way but I am unable to do:
for filename in glob.glob('*.json'):
            with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as json_data:
                data = json.load(json_data)
                namelist=[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Thank you @johnashu for the help. I did it using the below code. I made list of lists.

```
import glob
import json
import re 
lists = [[] for k in range(100)]
m=0
for filename in glob.glob('*.json'):

    with open(filename, encoding="utf8") as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)

        i=0
        for r in data['TweetsList']:
            line0= data["TweetsList"][i]["pubTime"]                  
            lists[m].append(line0)
            i+=1

    m+=1
```

Comment: Glad you solved it!! You should have said it was twitter!! :)

Comment: Also please select the correct answer for any future visitors!

Answer (score 1):

You can put them into lists but then you would have to create and initialise 400 lists!!

A far better approach is to put them into a dictionary with the keys being the filename and the values being the data.

```
import glob, json
from datetime import datetime

json_dict = {}
for filename in glob.glob('*.json'): 
    with open(filename, 'r') as json_data: 
        data = json.load(json_data)
        json_dict[filename] = data


def find_dates(filename):
    for k, v in json_dict.items():
        if k == filename:
            for key, value in v.items():
                for k1, v1 in value.items():
                    if k1 == 'publishTime':
                        return v1


date_1 = datetime.strptime(find_dates('jimmy.json'), '%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')

date_2 = datetime.strptime(find_dates('john.json'), '%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')

diff = date_2 - date_1

print(diff)
```

Prints out:

```
1 day, 0:04:00
```

Comment: so basically, I have a Json file, 100006.json. In that, I have attribute "publishTime": "9:38 AM - 4 Mar 2015". Similarly, there are different publish time. I have to find the difference between the first and the last publish time. I have to do the same for other 400 Json files. Earlier I was doing it using list, I stored the first and last publish time in the first and last element of list and did their subtraction, I cannot do this for all 400 files, so want to know the solution. I am new to Stackoverflow, so don't know the correct way also of asking questions.

Comment: try that... of course you may need to fine tune it as i dont know what the json data looks like!